# No EJB found with interface when built as jar

Tags: deployment, jar, ejb, wildfly, war

I have the following error when deploying and starting the application with Wildfly.

No EJB found with interface of type "de.dev.java.project.api.ProjectApi" for binding de.dev.java.project.restservice.ProjectRestService/projectApi.

```
Project module structure: 
- project-api   -> built as jar
   - ProjectApi.java
- project-impl  -> built as jar
   - ProjectRestService.java
     {
         @EJB ProjectApi projectApi
      }
- application -> built as ear, which includes modules above
```

I only have a problem when i build "project-impl" module as jar. When i built as war i do not have a problem. What does war include which jar does not?

Answer (score 0):

You must build as a proper ejb jar, not just regular jar. It also needs to be referenced properly in the ear. Use you IDE to setup suitable maven project with the right archetype